# Which culture media is suitable for cheek epithelial cells?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, cell-culture

A month ago, I tried isolating cheek cells from saliva and the experiment was a success, however, I was wondering if it is possible to cultivate these cells in vitro. I'd say it's possible, but I wasn't able to find any publications about this topic online, even on PubMed (I found one, but it was outdated and the part with used media wasn't clear). Is it possible to use just DMEM media and if so, how long will the cells survive in the media, or are there any other alternatives?

Comment: There are different kinds of epithelial cell basal media. These are also usually supplemented by different factors. I cannot find a medium specific to oral mucosa and the composition of the basal medium is difficult to find. [This paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1167/iovs.13-12866) says that DMEM supplemented with human serum or conditioned with fibroblast supports growth of conjunctival epithelial cells.